# why tikz will generate a series of .0.0.0.0?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, coordinates, fun

I want to generate several point on a line, and this is the command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % this command generate a series of .0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
    \foreach \i in {-2,...,1}{\fill ({random(-40,36)/10+0.2},0.2) circle (0.2cm); };    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Very thanks!

=========================update======================================

Thanks for percusse, the problem is in the negative parameter of function random. Just change like this:

```
  \foreach \i in {-2,...,1}{\fill ({(random(0,76)-40)/10+0.2},0.2) circle (0.2cm); };
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  It is best to provide a complete minimum document demonstrating the problem rather than just a code snippet, see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @percusse I added a CW answer to the other question.